# How to have a single scroll bar controlling four listboxes in Pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have some stock control python code, where I have 4 listboxes but I need all of them to be synchronized with a single scrollbar.

I need to use a listbox exclusively — I cannot use something else.

If someone can help, follow the code below:

````
def Filtrar():
    
    #mudar tema
    sg.change_look_and_feel('DarkGreen')


    Nome = ''
    Quantidade = ''
    Preco = ''
    Id = ''
    
    #layout
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Selecione a classe que deseja ver:',size=(15,0)),sg.InputCombo(('Circuito','Transistor'),size=(20,0),key='combo')],
        [sg.Button('Consultar')], 
        [sg.Text('ID'),sg.Text('                      '),sg.Text('Produto'),sg.Text('                    '),sg.Text('Quantidade'),sg.Text('  '),sg.Text('Preço')],
        [sg.Listbox(Id, size=(5,10), key='-BOX0-'),
        sg.Listbox(Nome, size=(25, 10), key='-BOX-'),
        sg.Listbox(Quantidade, size=(10, 10), key='-BOX2-'),
        sg.Listbox(Preco, size=(10, 10), key='-BOX3-')],
        [sg.Button('Deletar')],
        [sg.Button('Sair'),sg.Button('Voltar')]
        ]
        
    #janela
    window = sg.Window("adicionar ao Estoque",layout)

    while True:
        event,values = window.read()

        
        if event == 'Consultar':
            f = values['combo']
            Id = filtrar2(f)
            Nome = filtrar(f)
            Quantidade = filtrar3(f)
            Preco = filtrar4(f)
            
            window.find_element('-BOX-').Update(Nome)
            window.find_element('-BOX0-').Update(Id)
            window.find_element('-BOX2-').Update(Quantidade)
            window.find_element('-BOX3-').Update(Preco)
            
      
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Sair':
            window.close()
            break

        if event == 'Voltar':
            window.close()
            initi()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

For better appearance, some tkinter codes added,

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 12))

cols = 3
rows = 50
rows_show = 10
col_width = 15

data = [[f'Cell ({j:0>2d} ,{i:0>2d})' for i in range(rows)] for j in range(cols)]

all_listbox = [[sg.Listbox(data[i], size=(15, rows), pad=(0, 0),
    no_scrollbar=True, enable_events=True, key=f'listbox {i}',
    select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE) for i in range(cols)]]

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Product'.center(col_width), pad=(0, 0)),
     sg.Text('Unit Price'.center(col_width), pad=(0, 0)),
     sg.Text('Price'.center(col_width), pad=(0, 0))],
    [sg.Column(all_listbox, size=(555, 600), pad=(0, 0), scrollable=True,
        vertical_scroll_only=True)],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
for i in range(cols):
    listbox = window[f'listbox {i}'].Widget
    listbox.configure(justify='center')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if event.startswith('listbox'):
        row = window[event].get_indexes()[0]
        user_event = False
        for i in range(cols):
            window[f'listbox {i}'].set_value([])
            window[f'listbox {i}'].Widget.selection_set(row)

window.close()
```